# Does TensorBoard (TensorFlow) have the features to add labels for axes and legends on plots? If so, how?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I need to know how to add legend and label axes on TensorBoard (TensorFlow) graphs. Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

As of today (5/25/17), no. Someone submitted this as a [feature request](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7631), and Dandelion Mané (from the Tensorflow dev team) labeled the issue as "contributions welcome".

Comment: If you would like to see this implemented, you should +1 the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem recently, and even though the question is very old, but still -as of today- no solution from Tensorboard's team for this issue yet.

For those of you who are still looking for a solution, I decided to write a simple Tensorboard plugin as a workaround for this issue.

### Usage

```bash
pip install tensorboard-plugin-customizable-plots
```

After running Tensorboard, a new tab labeled `CUSTMOZIABLE PLOTS` will be added to the Tensorboard dashboard.

From there you can customize the legend and the axis labels of each plot.

The plugin is hosted on Github:
[tensorboard_plugin_customizable_plots](https://github.com/abdeladim-s/tensorboard_plugin_customizable_plots)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33489796)

Comment: @Mike_H yes I agree, I edited the answer to include the basic instructions on how to use the plugin in case the link becomes invalid. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct option, but this may help...
Once you load tensorBoard, enable "Show data download links."
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYzlU.png)
then, go to the graph; under the figure, click on "run to download" and select from the dropdown if you have multiple plot data.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qP7pH.png)
Then, CSV or JSON formatted data will show as an option to download the data. Select, e.g., CSV plot it using, e.g., matplotlib